# How to handle Softkeyboard on tab(actionbar)

Tags: android

I am using `ActionBar` with three Tab's.

My one Tab contain an `EditText` .

Requirment:-

1-After click on `EditText`  `VirtualKeyboard` should display.

2- and after clicking on other two `Tabs`.Keyboard should be hide.

It is working  fine.

Problem:-

After rotating the screen ,keyboard is hiding on that EditText.(land to prort)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"    
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    ...
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ..i got my solution.

Comment: This is only for Activity not for Fragments.